# Dynamically generated div doesn't populate Select element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add dynamic content to a page, but I can't get it to work properly.

I have a `user` div, on button click a new `user` is being added.

The `user` section:

```html
<div class="sec">
    <div class="sec">
        <input class="co" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value: name" />
        <div class="selectCont">
            <select id="status" class="coS" data-bind="options: $root.positions(), optionsText: 'position', optionsValue: 'id', value: $root.selectedPosition, optionsCaption: 'Select one'"></select>
        </div>
        <div><div class="lbl e">Email</div> <input class="coEmail co" data-bind="value: email" /></div>
        <div><div class="lbl p">Phone</div> <input class="coPhone co" data-bind="value: phoneNumber" /></div>
        <div>
            <div class="lbl f">Fax</div> <input class="coPhone co" data-bind="value: fax" />
            <div class="selectCont">
                <select class="coSel" id="contactStatus" data-bind="value: isPrimaryUser == true ? 'Primary' : 'Additional'">
                    <option>Additional</option>
                    <option>Primary</option>
                </select>
                <img class="selectArrow" src="~/Images/drop.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

//By clicking on a `+` button:

  <div class="secInner">
         <div class="add" data-bind="click: function(){ $root.addUserDiv()}"><div class="hor"></div></div>
  </div>

//I'm pushing a new `user` to the `users` array:
self.addUserDiv = function () {
    users.push(new user(""));
}
```

The new div is being added but the 2 `select` elements on the div don't get populated.

Please see attached example, the first one is the div that was originally on the page and the second one is the one that was just added, I can't access the two select options. on the new `user`
[image]

How can I get it to work?

Comment: To be clear, is your problem that the UI isn't updating ("the 2 `select` elements on the div don't get populated"), or that the data isn't being passed in the first place?  In other words, if you `console.log` the missing data, does it show up as expected?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel the data isn't being passed in the first place...

Comment: Does `self.addUserDiv` ever get reached? For example if you log the word "banana" in that function, does it show up when you click the `+` button?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel Sure, it's being reached: the new `div` is being added but without the `Select` elements..

Comment: Gotcha. The thing that confuses me is the `users.push(new user(""));`. I feel like it should be `users.push(new user("a bunch of JSON or something containing the select elements"));`. Maybe I am missing something blatant, but it seems to me that you're pushing nothing (`""`) ... and getting nothing, which kind of makes sense.

Comment: @MaxvonHippel I'm not sure because I do need an empty `div` \ `user`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148814/discussion-between-max-von-hippel-and-user3378165).